# How to add a custom image/icon in ANTD Design menu?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Using this example: https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-side

How can I add a custom image or icon instead of the default icons.

I tried:

```
<Menu.Item to="/" key="2">
  <img className="ant-menu-item" src={require('image.png')} />
  <span>Shopify</span>
  <Link to="/shopify">Home</Link>
</Menu.Item>
```

But that does not look good or does not respect the collapsed behaviour

Comment: The [official Ant Design docs](https://ant.design/components/icon/#Custom-SVG-Icon) have an entire section dedicated for this. Their tutorial has all the code you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Menu.Item to="/" key="2">
    <img className="ant-menu-item" src=="{{ "image.png" | asset_url }}"/>
    <span>Shopify</span>
    <Link to="/shopify">Home</Link>
</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work in the current version of antd (3.23.1). See my answer for the way I solved it.

Answer (score 15):

I tried several different ways of creating custom icons, and the one that was easiest and worked best was to use the `component` property of the antd `Icon` component. Just give it a functional component that returns whatever image you want to use:

```
<Icon component={() => (<img src="/image.svg" />)} />
```

This seems to work well within menu items and submenus, except that the icons don't line up perfectly with the menu text like the built-in icons do. I ended up adding `transform: translateY(-3px)` to the CSS to compensate for this (might depend on the image you use).

On the other hand, the [official solution](https://ant.design/components/icon/#Custom-SVG-Icon) (for SVG images only) is to use the [@svgr/webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) to turn the SVG file into a component. This may have some advantages as far as layout and coloring (antd icons seem to prefer actual `<svg>` elements over `<img>` elements with SVG image files). But I'm not sure because I didn't go to the trouble of setting it up.

Comment: Were you able to extend custom icon use within the route/menu in config.ts ?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old question, but I thought I'd post another solution here for those not wanting to go the `webpack` route like the docs recommend. You can simply create your own SVG component and then pass it to the antd icon component.

Something like this

```
// Icons.tsx
export const MyIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg>
       // svg path data
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Then

```
// app.tsx
import Icon from "@ant-design/icons";
import { MyIcon } from "./Icons";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Icon component={MyIcon} />
    )
}
```

I fiddled with this a little bit in a sandbox, and it seems to work just fine. I was using antd 4.23.3 for reference. Didn't test it a huge amount so there might be some style adjusting needed, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be work. 
you need handle separate css file and put it this code

```
.ant-menu-item{background-image: url("theme5.jpg");}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
icon:<img src="/static/icons/BH_tainan.svg"  height={20} style={{margin:"0 12px 0 0" ,paddingTop:10 ,float:"left"}}/>,
```

need float:"left" in your style