# Customize Ant Design Card bottom action icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I would like to customize Ant Design Card bottom action icons in React.

```
<Card
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    cover={
      <img
        alt="example"
        src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png"
      />
    }
    actions={[
      <SettingOutlined key="setting" />,
      <EditOutlined key="edit" />,
      <EllipsisOutlined key="ellipsis" />,
    ]}
  >
    <Meta
      avatar={<Avatar src="https://joeschmoe.io/api/v1/random" />}
      title="Card title"
      description="This is the description"
    />
  </Card>,
```

Is there a way to change the size of SettingOutlined, EditOutlined icons, to make them bigger?
Is there also a way to use instead my own icons that are not part of the "ant-design/icons" list ?

Comment: `<SettingOutlined  key="setting" style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />`

Comment: To create custom Icon: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644960/how-to-add-a-custom-image-icon-in-antd-design-menu)